# Transitioning underlines for multiple lines of Text

Tags: html, css

**Recently** I noticed that `text-decoration: underline` cannot be animated(transitioned). After a bit of research, I discover that the best and most common solution is to use `border-bottom`. But as you will see in this code snippet below, `border-bottom` isn't the best solution in this case.

```css
#borderText {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
 transition: .5s;
}

#borderText:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#textDecor {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s;
  }

#textDecor:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<p id="borderText">
  Lorem Ipsum Sit Amet<br />
  Some other Text<br />
  Some Other Text<br />
</p>

<p id="textDecor">
  Here is some text<br />
  with text-decoration and<br />
  as you should see, the text<br />
  is underlined but cannot be transitioned<br />
</p>
```

For the sake of clarification I will explain the problem and the goal:

**The Problem:** How can you transition a text underline with multiple lines of text?

**Goal:** To efficiently solve the problem above, and hopefully without any hacks.

Now, if it is impossible without certain hacks in place, which I personally suspect, provide SIMPLE hacks, PLEASE No markup absurdities such as putting every word inside of a span element.

Comment: why you think `border-bottom` is not good solution?

Comment: I need the text-underline for all lines of text.

Comment: well, you can do this with same `border-bottom`

Comment: Sorry, wasnt aware of using display: inline;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#borderText {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
 transition: .5s;
 display: inline;
cursor: pointer;
}

#borderText:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#textDecor {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s;
  }

#textDecor:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<p id="borderText">
  Lorem Ipsum Sit Amet<br />
  Some other Text<br />
  Some Other Text<br />
</p>

<p id="textDecor">
  Here is some text<br />
  with text-decoration and<br />
  as you should see, the text<br />
  is underlined but cannot be transitioned<br />
</p>
```

```css
#borderText {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
 transition: .5s;
}

#borderText:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#textDecor {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s;
  }

#textDecor:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<p id="borderText">
  Lorem Ipsum Sit Amet<br />
  Some other Text<br />
  Some Other Text<br />
</p>

<p id="textDecor">
  Here is some text<br />
  with text-decoration and<br />
  as you should see, the text<br />
  is underlined but cannot be transitioned<br />
</p>
```

```css
#borderText {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
 transition: .5s;
}

#borderText:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#textDecor {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s;
  }

#textDecor:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<p id="borderText">
  Lorem Ipsum Sit Amet<br />
  Some other Text<br />
  Some Other Text<br />
</p>

<p id="textDecor">
  Here is some text<br />
  with text-decoration and<br />
  as you should see, the text<br />
  is underlined but cannot be transitioned<br />
</p>
```

```css
#borderText {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
 transition: .5s;
}

#borderText:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#textDecor {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .5s;
  }

#textDecor:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<p id="borderText">
  Lorem Ipsum Sit Amet<br />
  Some other Text<br />
  Some Other Text<br />
</p>

<p id="textDecor">
  Here is some text<br />
  with text-decoration and<br />
  as you should see, the text<br />
  is underlined but cannot be transitioned<br />
</p>
```